# Combining Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

In MySQL, how do you combine 2 foreign keys in a table to become a primary key?

I have two tables, one `Staff`, one `Roles`, each containing their own primary keys, `StaffID` and `RoleID`. I have created a third table called `StaffRole` which will contain the `StaffID` and `RoleID`, keeping in mind this is a one to many relationship, as a staff member may have 1 or more roles.

How would you combine the foreign key of `StaffID` and `RoleID` to create a new unique primary keys for the table `StaffRole`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, what you are describing is not a *one-to-many* relationship, but instead it is a *many-to-many* relationship since one `Staff` record relates to many `Role` records, but one `Role` record also relates to many different `Staff`. Your use of the join table `StaffRole` is the typical way of handling the relationship.

This is semantics, but it isn't really a matter of *combining* the two foreign keys, so much as just creating a third key which is the composite of the two and also the primary key.  So your table will have two `FOREIGN KEY` definitions, one each for the two columns, and one composite `PRIMARY KEY` definition across *both* of the columns.

```
CREATE TABLE StaffRole (
  StaffID INT NOT NULL,
  RoleID INT NOT NULL,
  /* Composite primary key on both columns */
  PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, RoleID),
  /* Two separate foreign keys */
  FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff (StaffID),
  FOREIGN KEY (RoleID) REFERENCES Roles (RoleID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Note, I have specified `InnoDB` as the table type, since MySQL will not enforce the `FOREIGN KEY`s on MyISAM tables.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a StaffRoleID as a primary key, and use StaffID and RoleID as foreign keys.